# taking photo with action_image_capture and "not" save them or delete before use

Tags: java, camera

in androidstudio, i want to take a photo with camera, use the photo, but when i finish i want to delete the photo, but it doesnt work.

1- i take a photo with action_camera_capture.

2- create a temp file

3- use the photo and save on the temp file

```
static final int TAKE_PHOTO= 1;
Intent takePhoto = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePhoto , TAKE_PHOTO);
```

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent datas){
Bitmap bitmapPH= (Bitmap) datas.getExtras().get("data");
ImageView imageOut= findViewById(R.id.imageViewSplashOut);
createImageFile(cellphone imei);
out = new FileOutputStream(photo);
bitmapPH.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, out); 
out.flush();
out.close();
imageOut.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image));
```

```
private File createImageFile(String imei) throws IOException {
        Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
        String time=  ca.getTimeInMillis() + "-";
        TextView value= findViewById(R.id.editValue);
        String valPin = value.getText().toString();
        String imageFileName =  valPin + "_no_" + time;
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir     /* directory */
        );
        String photo= image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

i expect, take a photo, use these but when i finish i want to delete... but it doesnt delete, i see the photo in gallery

Comment: for resolve this, i delete the last photo in gallery if i have some in last 5 second ---
Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified()); --- 
Long date = lastModDate.getTime(); --- ((date+5000) > fechaCreacion) deleteImage(file)

Comment: in my case, maybe i want to use the photo later, for this i create new file with the photo, and delete it before i use